# Delphi - Writing a program that reads a series of numbers and adds them up until the user enters 0

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe2, delphi-2010, delphi-2009

**This is where I am at So far and when I enter a number in the edit box and press the button it crashes, I am a newbie to Delphi please help! Thanks, Matt**

```
var
  Form3: TForm3;
  Count: integer;
  RunningTotal: Real;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}



procedure TForm3.btnEnterClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 repeat

   RunningTotal:= RunningTotal + STRTOINT (edtNum.Text);
 until STRTOINT(edtNum.Text)=0;
  lblAns.Caption:= FLOATTOSTR (RunningTotal);

end;

procedure TForm3.edtNumChange(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
Count:=0;
RunningTotal:=0;
end;

end.
```

Comment: You're looping inside the code when the enter key has been pressed. The user never gets an opportunity to enter another number or change the contents of `edtNum`. So the loop will run forever (unless they enter 0 first).

Comment: Also, when posting questions which include phrases like "crash" or "error", it helps to include the contents of any error messages that are displayed. I'm guessing that, in this case, it's something about an overflow.

Comment: "it crashes" is no good for us. You can see the exact error message. We cannot. Please don't make us guess. Tell us what the error is!

Comment: The task reads like a homework to be done with a console application in good old Turbo Pascal days.

Comment: I would typically downvote questions like this in a heartbeat, but I'll be nice since you're brand new to Delphi.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I hope you learn to like it here.  Posting a question that looks like homework raises all kinds of flags for people, because it's ethically questionable for people to contribute to what looks like a request to crib your answers from someone else instead of learning to do beginner steps on your own.  Good luck in your programming adventures. I believe that the "close" really means "this question doesn't really belong on here". Try not to take that too hard.

Answer (score 1):

You're looping forever when the user provides his first value.  All you need to do in the event handler is take a single value, and process it.

```
procedure TForm3.btnEnterClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if STRTOINT(edtNum.Text)=0 then
    lblAns.Caption:= FLOATTOSTR (RunningTotal)
  else
    RunningTotal:= RunningTotal + STRTOINT (edtNum.Text);
end;
```

This way the user can submit further numbers, until he supplies you a `0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you will type a character instead of a number it will result in a exception.You can treat the exception or you can prevent the user from entering characters like this

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  myvalue : Real = 0;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}



procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  number : Real;
begin
  number := StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
  if number = 0 then ShowMessageFmt('The result is %f',[myvalue])
  else
  myvalue := myvalue + number;
  Edit1.Text := '';
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if not (Key in ['0'..'9','.']) then Key := #0;
end;
```

Comment: Good. You get an A on his homework.